# Tracking the origination of a Google Doc

Tags: google-docs

I am a recent victim of "revenge porn."  Unfortunately a crazy ex-girl friend of my ex-boyfriend, found some personal pictures of me (that he never deleted)  and posted them online in a Google Doc.  I don't know how long it was up there, and I have contacted Google who took down the Doc, but **is there a way to prove where it originated?**  I would like to press charges since this will damage my career.  **Also is it possible to get the pics back?**

Comment: It's technically possible but very specific on a case by case basis, someone with the technical knowledge could trace back whoever posted a file. You mentioned however that that the file has been taken down, which means this is no longer a possibility. - That given most google docs will usually have the owner/creators gmail account associated with it, and if this women was dumb enough to use her own gmail it would be very easy to sue. Advice about pressing charges is however best directed to https://law.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that this has happened to you.

Unfortunately, unlike a Microsoft Word document, a Google Doc really doesn't have the same sort of meta information like the licensed owner of the software, version, etc.

I'm sure Google has that information though, but to get that you would need to pursue legal remedy, which is far beyond the ken of this site. You should get in touch with a lawyer to see what your options are.